# Misalignment of multi-line questions with 3-digit question numbers (exam class)

Tags: spacing, exam

I'm creating a large question paper using the `exam` package, with over 100 questions. The problem is that for question numbers over 100, the extra digit causes multi-line questions to misalign, with the lines after the first coming slightly under the last digit of the question number.

An example of what I mean:
[image]

Is there some way to edit the margin space in which the question number appears to fix this misalignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\questionshook` to change the default definition for `\makelabel`; for example, the following definition aligns the labels to the right and adds some extra space for the labels (change the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{exam}

\renewcommand\questionshook{%
  \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{\makebox[17pt][r]{##1}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\setcounter{question}{97}
\question
Why is there air?
\question
Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$. 
\question How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood? How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood? 
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]